# Phased transition from php to node server

Tags: php, node.js

I am working on a site that is hosted on

> goDaddy, through cPanel

The client wants to transition from their old PHP server to a node.js system.

They would like to implement new code in phases while leaving the old site up and running. The old and new code would be running on the same server.

I have a good break point for phase 1, but am not sure how to allow the PHP and node code to run simultaneously and listening for requests on the same server. I am familiar with node, but not as much with PHP.

In short- Can I have PHP and Node.js running simultaneously on the same server? If so, what considerations need to be made? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Run them on different ports? Use a second server? What exactly is the question? Too broad.

Comment: Nginx, as one example, can be configured to delegate to PHP or Node.js depending on the particular path involved. You can slowly migrate one path from the PHP stack to the Node stack over time.

Comment: Thank you for asking for the clarification. I have edited the question with a brief summary to add clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely want to make it to where you migrate to the node.js service one endpoint at a time. That way you can test, debug, and fix things quickly without too much work. I recommend you use express for your router and whatever database connector you want. You will want to canary test between the two as well.